# How to run AWS ECS Task with CloudFormation overriding container environment variables

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I was searching a way to run ecs task. I already have a cluster and task definition settings. I just wanted to trigger a task using CloudFormation template. I know that I can run a task by clicking on the console and it works fine. For cfn, approach needs to be define properly.

Check the attached screenshots. I wanted to run that task using CloudFormation and pass container override environment variables. As per my current templates, it is not allowing me to do same like I can do using console. Using console I just need to select the following options

```
  1. Launch type 
  2. Task Definition 
              Family
              Revision 
  3. VPC and security groups 
  4. Environment variable overrides rest of the things automatically selected
```

It starts working with console but with cloudformaton template how can we do that. Is it possible to do or there is no such feature?

```
      "taskdefinition": {
    "Type" : "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
    "DependsOn": "DatabaseMaster",
    "Properties" : {
        "ContainerDefinitions" : [{
            "Environment" : [
              {
                 "Name" : "TARGET_DATABASE",
                 "Value" : {"Ref":"DBName"}
              },
              {
                 "Name" : "TARGET_HOST",
                 "Value" : {"Fn::GetAtt": ["DatabaseMaster", "Endpoint.Address"]}
              }
            ]
          }],
        "ExecutionRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
        "Family" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "TaskRoleArn" : "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:role/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-XXXXXXXXX"
    }
  },
  "EcsService": {
    "Type" : "AWS::ECS::Service",
    "Properties" : {
        "Cluster" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "LaunchType" : "FARGATE",
        "NetworkConfiguration" : {
               "AwsvpcConfiguration" : {
                      "SecurityGroups" : ["sg-xxxxxxxxxxx"],
                      "Subnets" : ["subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
                      }
           },
        "TaskDefinition" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
  }
```

[image]

[image: ECS Run Task by using aws console]

**There is no validity error in the code however, I am talking about the approach. I added image name container name but now it is asking for memory and cpu, it should not ask as it is already defined we just need to run a task.**

**Edited**

I wanted to run a task after creation of my database and wanted to pass those database values to the task to run and complete a job.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working example of what you can do if you wanted to pass variable and run a task. In my case, I wanted to run a task after creation of my database but with environment variables, directly AWS does not provide any feature to do so, this is the solution which can help to trigger you ecs task.

```
"IAMRole": {
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
    "Properties": {
      "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": [
                "events.amazonaws.com"
              ]
            },
            "Action": [
              "sts:AssumeRole"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "Description": "Allow CloudWatch Events to trigger ECS task",
      "Policies": [
        {
          "PolicyName": "Allow-ECS-Access",
          "PolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
              {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                  "ecs:*",
                  "iam:PassRole",
                  "logs:CreateLogStream",
                  "logs:PutLogEvents"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "RoleName": { "Fn::Join": [ "", ["CloudWatchTriggerECSRole-", { "Ref": "DBInstanceIdentifier" }]]}
    }
  },
  "DummyParameter": {
      "Type" : "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
      "Properties" : {
          "Name" : {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-${DatabaseMaster}-EndpointAddress"},
          "Type" : "String",
          "Value" : {"Fn::GetAtt": "DatabaseMaster.Endpoint.Address"}
      },
      "DependsOn": "TaskSchedule"
  },
  "TaskSchedule": {
    "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
    "Properties": {
      "Description": "Trigger ECS task upon creation of DB instance",
      "Name": { "Fn::Join": [ "", ["ECSTaskTrigger-", { "Ref": "DBName" }]]},
      "RoleArn": {"Fn::GetAtt": "IAMRole.Arn"},
      "EventPattern": {
          "source": [ "aws.ssm" ],
          "detail-type": ["Parameter Store Change"] ,
          "resources": [{"Fn::Sub":"arn:aws:ssm:eu-west-1:XXXXXXX:parameter/${AWS::StackName}-${DatabaseMaster}-EndpointAddress"}],
          "detail": {
              "operation": ["Create"],
              "name": [{"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}-${DatabaseMaster}-EndpointAddress"}],
              "type": ["String"]
          }
      },
      "State": "ENABLED",
      "Targets": [
        {
          "Arn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx:cluster/NameOf-demo",
          "Id": "NameOf-demo",
          "RoleArn": {"Fn::GetAtt": "IAMRole.Arn"},
          "EcsParameters": {
            "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
            "NetworkConfiguration": {
              "AwsVpcConfiguration": {
                "SecurityGroups": {"Ref":"VPCSecurityGroups"},
                "Subnets": {"Ref":"DBSubnetName"}
              }
            },
            "PlatformVersion": "LATEST",
            "TaskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXX:task-definition/NameXXXXXXXXX:1"
          },
          "Input": {"Fn::Sub": [
              "{\"containerOverrides\":[{\"name\":\"MyContainerName\",\"environment\":[{\"name\":\"VAR1\",\"value\":\"${TargetDatabase}\"},{\"name\":\"VAR2\",\"value\":\"${TargetHost}\"},{\"name\":\"VAR3\",\"value\":\"${TargetHostPassword}\"},{\"name\":\"VAR4\",\"value\":\"${TargetPort}\"},{\"name\":\"VAR5\",\"value\":\"${TargetUser}\"},{\"name\":\"VAR6\",\"value\":\"${TargetLocation}\"},{\"name\":\"VAR7\",\"value\":\"${TargetRegion}\"}]}]}",
              {
                  "VAR1":      {"Ref":"DBName"},
                  "VAR2":          {"Fn::GetAtt": ["DatabaseMaster", "Endpoint.Address"]},
                  "VAR3":  {"Ref":"DBPassword"},
                  "VAR4":          "5432",
                  "VAR5":          {"Ref":"DBUser"},
                  "VAR6":      "value6",
                  "VAR7":        "eu-west-2"
              }
          ]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Fargate task, we need to specify in CPU in [Task Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-cpu). and memory or memory reservation in either task or container definition.

and environment variables should be passed to each container as ContainerDefinitions and overrided when task is run from ecs task-run from console or cli.

```
{
   "ContainerTaskdefinition": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
      "Properties": {
         "Family": "SomeFamily",
         "ExecutionRoleArn": !Ref RoleArn,
         "TaskRoleArn": !Ref TaskRoleArn,
         "Cpu": "256",
         "Memory": "1GB",
         "NetworkMode": "awsvpc",
         "RequiresCompatibilities": [
            "EC2",
            "FARGATE"
         ],
         "ContainerDefinitions": [
            {
               "Name": "container name",
               "Cpu": 256,
               "Essential": "true",
               "Image": !Ref EcsImage,
               "Memory": "1024",
               "LogConfiguration": {
                  "LogDriver": "awslogs",
                  "Options": {
                     "awslogs-group": null,
                     "awslogs-region": null,
                     "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                  }
               },
               "Environment": [
                  {
                     "Name": "ENV_ONE_KEY",
                     "Value": "Valu1"
                  },
                  {
                     "Name": "ENV_TWO_KEY",
                     "Value": "Valu2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT(from discussion in comments):
ECS Task Run is not a cloud-formation resource, it can only be run from console or CLI.
But if we choose to run from a cloudformation resource, it can be done using cloudformation custom resource. But once task ends, we now have a resource in cloudformation without an actual resource behind. So, custom resource needs to do:

- on create: run the task.
- on delete: do nothing.
- on update: re-run the task

Force an update by changing an attribute or logical id, every time we need to run the task.

Comment: But, using console there is no such option. If our task definition is already defined then why we need to again define it?

Comment: so, you have created task definition manually , you only want to create service in cloudformation, but your cloudformation template in question is trying to create the task definition again though, But all you need to create is a service using existing task definition correct and you need CF for that?

Comment: I created task definition using cdk, I can adjust cdk to run on schedule but that is not a requirement,  just only want to run task to run my solution whenever my CloudFormation template executed. So that is why I am adding task running part in CloudFormation, to run only when need. Now the question is how can I achieve this like using console where I don't need to mentioned cpu ram etc. I am talking about task not service. To run a task just. Creating services is something else. Please see the screenshots

Comment: i don't think task run is actual resource, so, we need a service or schedule task. We can probably run a task with a custom resource but what happens if that task is complete or dies, are we struck with a resource with in cloud-formation with out an actual resource? But I guess, with custom resource which runs the task and you can trigger some change to the resource to re-trigger the update resource which creates the task again, deleting resource from cf will simply ignore?

Comment: My task is just a job which restore database from s3 and stops after restoring successfully or not successfully. It just killed, using console I can do this and it is working fine but using cfn how cab w do this? as this is not a schedule, it should run after creation of database because in my my template database is being created so after that I need to restore backup from s3 and my task is doing that work, to automate that stuff, I need to trigger task with variables which will make it more generic and reusable.

Comment: ok.sounds good. custom resource is only way I can think of!

Comment: Check the solution below to run a task.

Comment: cool! I see you went with cloudwatch event rule!

Comment: Yes, because this is the only way, otherwise you need to create task definition, if you have everything already then you just need trigger with some value

Comment: Question is more about cloud-formation for [ecs task run](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html) which is not something that is supported via cloduformation. Two options we have(other than running via cli) to run ecs task, one ECS service , second scheduled task (from cloudwatch event rule) is pretty common pattern, i mentioned in one of the comments above, probably didn't mention cloudwath event rule. But thats the only way to schedule a task :)

Comment: That is why I clearly mentioned all detail in my question and I showed you my CFN template, actually its automation, and all resources are being creating with master and nested stack, the only things which is already created is ecs task definition, so we just need to run it once database created because ecs task is restoring data into database. And it should only be trigger when database is created so schedule task with some time like cron will not work. We need to trigger when db is created so that is why I used parameter store to add the value and after that it triggers and worked fine.

Comment: I am glad it worked. Sorry I could help more. We can also look at RDS events rather than SSM parm!